# How to judge whether a key is in the other dictionaries of a dictionary list(at least occurred in 2 different dictionaries) with python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, svm

I am creating a support vector and I have a dictionary list with 1000 dictionaries. Also there are at least 200 items in each dictionary. What I want to do is to judge whether a key occurred in at least two dictionaries. For example

```
dicts = [{"ab":3,"bc":4},{"ac":3;"df":3},{"ab":2,"de":4}...]
```

How can I judge "ab" is in other dictionaries besides{"ab":3,"bc":4} and "ac" is in other dictionaries besides {"ac":3;"df":3} and "de" is in other dictionaries besides {"ab":2,"de":4}
My code is

```
for dct in dicts:
    for key in dct:
        for dct1 in dicts:
            if((dct != dct1) and (key in dct1)):
                training_vector.append(key)
```

But it took a very long time to get my result. Therefore, could you show me a more effective method or give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid doing an O(n^2) search you can create a new dict that contains the index in `dicts` of each key. Eg,

```
dicts = [{"ab":3, "bc":4},{"ac":3, "df":3},{"ab":2, "de":4}]
print 'dicts', dicts

master = {}
for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
    for k in d:
        master.setdefault(k, []).append(i)

print 'master', master
```

**Output**

```
dicts [{'ab': 3, 'bc': 4}, {'df': 3, 'ac': 3}, {'de': 4, 'ab': 2}]
master {'df': [1], 'ac': [1], 'ab': [0, 2], 'de': [2], 'bc': [0]}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? My answer helps the OP without providing a complete working solution...